# Python 2.7 error: name 'wine' is not defined

Tags: python

I get the error message "NameError: name 'wine' is not defined" whenever I run the following code:

```
def pub():
 print ("Welcome to the pub; what will you be drinking tonight?")
 answer = input("Choose the type of beverage you desire")
 if answer == " Beer" or answer == " beer":
    print ("You've come to the right place; have a seat!")
 elif answer == " Wine" or answer == " wine":
    print ("Sorry, we don't serve wine here. Why don't you try next door?")
 elif answer == " Cocktails" or answer == " cocktails" : 
    print ("Cocktails? who drinks those anymore?")
 elif answer == " Liquor" or answer == " liquor":
    print ("Sorry, we don't serve hard drinks here.")
 else:
    print ("You didn't pick a legitimate drink; try again!") 
pub()
def beer_selection():
   print ("Now we need to know what types of beers you're into. Select one of      the \
following flavor profiles:")
flavor_profiles = ["Rich and malty", "Crisp and hoppy", "Light and fruity",    "Smooth and balanced", "Piney and hoppy"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it really the whole script?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
raw_input()
```

instead of:

```
input()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your input is being evaluated. This is the behavior of `input()` in Python 2.x. Since you have no variable named `wine`, an exception is thrown. You can check this behavior by typing `" Wine"` (with the double quotes), which works fine because it is now being entered as a string rather than a variable name.

You can use `raw_input()` instead, which will work with your value `Wine`, ie:

```
answer = raw_input("Choose the type of beverage you desire")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using python 2.7

for python 2.7 the 'input' is 'raw_input'

replace input function with this

```
 answer = raw_input("Choose the type of beverage you desire:")
```

Comment: Okay; that was the issue. I was using python 3.5 in the lab and forgotten that I had an older version installed on my computer at home. Thanks for the help everyone!